# Настройки игрового поля "Сапер"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

не работает prompt()

```
var game = {
  askStandartField: confirm("Стандартные настройки?"),
  width: 10,
  height: 10,
  mineCount: 9,
  standartField: (function() {
    if (!game.askStandartField) {
    game.width = prompt("Длина поля")
    game.height = prompt("Высота поля");
    game.mineCount = prompt("Кол-во мин:");
}
}
```

Вот весь код чтобы вы лучше понимали:

```js
var game = {
  askStandartField: confirm("Стандартные настройки?"),
  width: 10,
  height: 10,
  mineCount: 9,
  standartField: (function() {
    if (!game.askStandartField) {
      game.width = prompt("Длина поля")
      game.height = prompt("Высота поля");
      game.mineCount = prompt("Кол-во мин:");
    }
  })(),
  openCount: 0,
  field: [],
  fillField: function() {
    for (var x = 0; x < game.width; x++) {
      var row = [];
      game.field.push(row);
      for (var y = 0; y < game.height; y++) {
        row.push(new setCellState());
      }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < game.mineCount; i++) {
      var xx = Math.floor(Math.random() * game.width);
      var yy = Math.floor(Math.random() * game.height);
      if (!game.field[xx][yy].isMine) {
        game.field[xx][yy].isMine = true;
      } else {
        i--;
      }
    }
  },
  drawField: function() {
    $("body").append("<table id = 'table'>");
    for (var x = 0; x < game.width; x++) {
      $("table").append("<tr>");
      for (var y = 0; y < game.height; y++) {
        $("tr:last-child").append(`<td class="${game.field[x][y].isMine?'isMine':''}">`);
      }
    }
  }
};
game.fillField();
game.drawField();
$("td").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("isOpen");
});
```

Comment: Сейчас только забил Ваш код в консоль и всё сработало. Может adblock заблокировал?

Comment: Я оформил ваш код как [mcve], обратите внимание на ошибку в консоли. Причина ошибки - **объекта `game` не существует в момент вызова его метода `askStandartField`**. Объект будет создан и доступен только после выполнения выражения `var game = {...}`. Решением будет реализация не литералом, а в стиле ООП (с конструктором и прототипом). Подробнее об этом  - в букваре по JavaScript.

Comment: То есть, не метода, конечно же... *в момент обращения к _свойству_ `askStandartField` :) Смысл  тот же: объекта нет ➞ при обращении к его полям выбрасывается TypeError.

Answer (score 3):

Значения присваивающиеся полям литерала объекта вычисляются до того, как созданный объект присвоен указанной переменной, поэтому в случае

```
  standartField: (function() {
    if (!game.askStandartField) {
      game.width = prompt("Длина поля")
      game.height = prompt("Высота поля");
      game.mineCount = prompt("Кол-во мин:");
    }
  })(),
```

Внутри вызванной функции `game` будет `undefined`, так как функция вызывается раньше.

Исправить ошибку можно несколькими способами:

1. убрать вызов функции при инициализации объекта:

   ```
   standartField: (function() {
       if (!game.askStandartField) {
         game.width = prompt("Длина поля")
         game.height = prompt("Высота поля");
         game.mineCount = prompt("Кол-во мин:");
       }
   }),
   ```

   и вызвать затем эту функцию: `game.standartField();`
2. вообще убрать из объекта эти ненужные поля, так как они не хранят состояние объекта, а только инициализируют его. например:

   ```js
   var game = {
     width: 10,
     height: 10,
     mineCount: 9,
     openCount: 0,
     field: [],
     fillField: function() {
       for (var x = 0; x < game.width; x++) {
         var row = [];
         game.field.push(row);
         for (var y = 0; y < game.height; y++) {
           row.push(new setCellState());
         }
       }
       for (var i = 0; i < game.mineCount; i++) {
         var xx = Math.floor(Math.random() * game.width);
         var yy = Math.floor(Math.random() * game.height);
         if (!game.field[xx][yy].isMine) {
           game.field[xx][yy].isMine = true;
         } else {
           i--;
         }
       }
     },
     drawField: function() {
       $("body").append("<table id = 'table'>");
       for (var x = 0; x < game.width; x++) {
         $("table").append("<tr>");
         for (var y = 0; y < game.height; y++) {
           $("tr:last-child").append(`<td class="${game.field[x][y].isMine?'isMine':''}">`);
         }
       }
     }
   };

   function standartField() {
     if (!confirm("Стандартные настройки?")) {
       game.width = prompt("Длина поля")
       game.height = prompt("Высота поля");
       game.mineCount = prompt("Кол-во мин:");
     }
   }
   game.fillField();
   game.drawField();
   $("td").click(function() {
     $(this).addClass("isOpen");
   });
   ```
3. не использовать функцию, а инициализировать каждое поле отдельно:

   ```js
   var isStdFields = confirm("Стандартные настройки?");
   var game = {
     width: isStdFields ? 10 : prompt("Длина поля"),
     height: isStdFields ? 10 : prompt("Высота поля"),
     mineCount: isStdFields ? 9 : prompt("Кол-во мин:"),
     openCount: 0,
     field: [],
     fillField: function() {
       for (var x = 0; x < game.width; x++) {
         var row = [];
         game.field.push(row);
         for (var y = 0; y < game.height; y++) {
           row.push(new setCellState());
         }
       }
       for (var i = 0; i < game.mineCount; i++) {
         var xx = Math.floor(Math.random() * game.width);
         var yy = Math.floor(Math.random() * game.height);
         if (!game.field[xx][yy].isMine) {
           game.field[xx][yy].isMine = true;
         } else {
           i--;
         }
       }
     },
     drawField: function() {
       $("body").append("<table id = 'table'>");
       for (var x = 0; x < game.width; x++) {
         $("table").append("<tr>");
         for (var y = 0; y < game.height; y++) {
           $("tr:last-child").append(`<td class="${game.field[x][y].isMine?'isMine':''}">`);
         }
       }
     }
   };

   game.fillField();
   game.drawField();
   $("td").click(function() {
     $(this).addClass("isOpen");
   });
   ```